# How to manage development of PHP script?

Tags: php

When I am writing PHP i find it really hard to keep track of all the changes/bug fixes I make.

When you are creating a script in PHP what do you use to keep a track of any changes that you make along with adding version numbers and maintaining a changelog file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A version control system and a bug tracker...? This is more ontopic at http://programmers.stackexchange.com, and I'm sure there are lots of similar questions already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Versioning system. One of the most common is for example Subversion.
http://subversion.apache.org/

Subversion offers great features, like revision history, comparing between those revisions, also branching and tagging